# Requiring Data from PostGres and MySQL in one view

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have two databases one in PostgreSQL and other in MySQL. What I want is to get data from both databases and create a view and then iterate it on front-end.

Is it possible?.

Comment: Hi Malik. It'll be ideal if you provide what framework / language you're building this view in, as it's a bit hard to provide an answer with the current information. Please edit your answer with more detail.

Comment: I am using symfony 3.4 framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smartest thing to do would be to create two connections, one to each database, and handle it that way.

If you need to join the tables, you could consider using a [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) foreign table in PostgreSQL and join the tables in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That extension seams to be good did some checking in the code, remote query plan for local planning and prepare statements for MySQL seams to be supported ... Have one doubt about [this](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/blob/master/connection.c#L200)  not sure if this is possible to connect with a charset -> `CREATE SERVER mysql_server
     FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql_fdw
     OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', port '3306' charset 'utf8');` which makes a bit more sense

Comment: [These](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/blob/master/option.c#L61) are the options. For the server, you can use `host`, `port`, `init_command`, `secure_auth`, `use_remote_estimate` and the `ssl_*` options. Looks like you can use `init_command` to set the client encoding for MySQL.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing to that as i totally mist it.. now i think about it.. i believe `CREATE SERVER mysql_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql_fdw OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', port '3306' init_command 'SET NAMES utf8');` should be possible as it seams this extension is coded on the MySQL protocol specs.. For obvious reasons i would not use it if it wasn't possible to define the connection charset as prepared statements are not safe then because of possible (multibyte) character encoding injections..